# React JS: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, typeerror

I am working on an **ejected** React App created with **CRA Typescript** template. As soon as I run `npm start` command the app throws this error in browser:

**Error:**

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined.

**What all I have tried:**

- Fresh install using `npm i` after deleting package-lock.json and node_modules
- Clean install using `npm clean-install`
- Clearing npm using `npm cache clean --force`
- Installing the node version specified in `nvm`

**My Package JSON:**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^3.26.7",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-collapse": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-headroom": "^3.0.0",
    "react-jsx-parser": "^1.23.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.4",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.151",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-collapse": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-headroom": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/redux-form": "^8.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.8.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.5",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "resolve": "1.12.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.2.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.5",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

My development is stuck due to this issue.

Can you please guide me on how to resolve this, thanks :)

Comment: how is your package.json look like?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari I have added JSON.